# Displaying Web data, not web page, in Android

Tags: html, android, http, listview

I need display data from a web page in a ListView, for example if I were to send a request to a time server for the U.S. time zone's times and the web server responded with an HTML web page that contained the current time's of each zone and a small icon image of each geographic region time zone, what steps would I need to take to put that data into a ListView?

For example, if I use http to communicate with the time server, it will respond with an http response, will I have to somehow extract the HTML from the response and find the image of the geographic region as well as the text for the current time?  Is there a better way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the http request
Save the response (in memory, a string probably)
parse the response
display the parsed data

`will I have to somehow extract the HTML from the response`

How else would you do it?

`Is there a better way to do something like this?`

Find a site that offers an API

Answer (score 1):

Make the Android problem a separate problem, by **setting up a small server-side web application** that does the teasing apart information for you, and then **only deal with the JSON or XML** that you cook up for your mobile app.